# Disable EditItem in ribbon list view if the user is not listed in a column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list-view

is there a way I can disable EditItem icon on the ribbon. But enable the icon when user select the item that has their name in a column. I have sharepoint 2013. Thank you.

Comment: Depending on the size of your list you could setup item-level permissions.  This can be done with a SharePoint Designer Workflow.   Google this: How to Set SharePoint Item Level Permissions based on Column and Field Values

Answer (score 0):

Create a 2010 platform workflow then add actions as shown below:

[image]

Reference:

https://praveensharepointknowledgebase.wordpress.com/2015/03/17/item-level-permission-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow/